# Strongly Connected Components of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading about the [Kosaraju-Sharir Algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122181900080). How does having the reverse postorder and postorder of a DFS tree help you identify strongly connected components? According to [HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/strongly-connected-components/tutorial/), reversing the order somehow helps you identify sinks, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case other people are curious - I found an interesting comment in [Sedgewick's Algorithms](https://books.google.com/books?id=a9HYAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT139&lpg=PT139&dq=reverse%20postorder%20identify%20sinks&source=bl&ots=rBt7h46MoW&sig=ACfU3U0EkiRulc7TIZeDqC5AtnfM157x7Q&hl=en&ppis=_c&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikq7Sy9ufmAhUIZd8KHXhPDBAQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=reverse%20postorder%20identify%20sinks&f=false):

[image]

Not a full answer by any means, but I thought it might help.